# Node upgrade doesn't work in my case:

Tags: node.js

I want to upgrade node to the latest stable version ( 6.9.5 ) but it doesn't work:

```
# node -v
v0.10.37


# sudo npm cache clean -f 
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.


# sudo npm install -g n 
/usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
/usr/local/lib
└── n@2.1.4 


# sudo n 6.9.5

     install : node-v6.9.5
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.9.5
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-linux-x64.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
   installed : v6.9.5

# node -v
v0.10.37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify to use the version of node you just installed

```
n use 6.9.5 script.js
```

You can list node versions installed with `n` using

```
n
```

If you want to set your default node version you will need to change the path to your node binary, get it by executing:

```
n bin 6.9.5
```

In Linux, MacOS and BSD, in your .bashrc/.zshrc you should modify line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin
```

to refer to the path you got earlier.

On Windows set it similarly in the PATH variable in your system environment variables.

[Referencing docs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

Comment: just done but "node -v" still show me this: v0.10.37

Comment: Sorry, i misread the docs - i've updated my answer now - should solve your problem! When you run `node -v` your system is reading the location of nodejs from your `path`, your path is currently set to the old version of node!

Comment: A nicer way of handling all of this would be with nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm - which sets the environment variables/path variables for you!